# Small number appears in upper left corner on some pages, what is it?

Tags: header-footer

For some reason small numbers appear on some of the pages of my document. It is alsway in the upper left corner, like on the picture attached where the number 4 appears. I have found out that it could be due to \usepackage{minted} or something with the header-footer setup.

I have tried making an MWE, sorry for it being so long:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,citestyle = authoryear]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % Package to change header and footer
\usepackage{minted}         % To include MATLAB code
\usepackage{lastpage}       % To add "page x of xx" to footer

\fancypagestyle{main}{% All normal pages
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize} % - \rightmark
    \fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Chapter pages
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize} % - \leftmark
    \fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section something}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section something}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{minted}{matlab}
    #include "createRDeltaT.H"

Info<< "Reading field p_rgh\n" << endl;
volScalarField p_rgh
(
    IOobject
    (
        "p_rgh",
        runTime.timeName(),
        mesh,
        IOobject::MUST_READ,
        IOobject::AUTO_WRITE
    ),
    mesh
);
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how I can still use this usepackage without getting the small numbers on the pages?

[image: Picture showing the small number 4 in the upper left corner]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looks like a line number since it sits in the margin. But without any code, it is impossible to tell what is causing it. Try to come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You could make a copy from your file, and then delete as much from the code as possible so that the problem still remains. This should lead you to the problem. If you still need help, you may want to provide some code here.

Comment: Please share your preamble and some (random) contents that allows us to reproduce the issue. Otherwise we can only guess (like Jasper just did) and we cannot tell you what you need to do to actually resolve the issue.

Comment: Hm, I get a lot of errors when I compile your MWE. You should probably remove the line `\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}` since you already load `titlesec` above and you load the `xcolor` package which you should not necessarily combine with the `color` pacakge (which is older). Also, I think you should only use either `titleps` or `fancyhdr`.

Comment: You should *never* ignore errors, even if the PDF output looks right. Start from the first error you ecounter and solve all errors step by step. You may ignore warnings, but not errors! You've got an unclosed `\if` in the defintion of the `plain` page style `\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}` which seems to be the root of this problem. Add `\fi` at the end of this line, so that it becomes `\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}\fi` (or put it where it belongs, but it needs to be somewhere in your code).

Comment: Dear Jasper, thank you very much for your help :) the \fi solved the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that you've got an unclosed `\if` statement in your code. More precisely, in the definition of the `plain` page style (why exactly this leads to the small number would require digging deep into the code, which is probably unnecessary here). Actually, this should have given you an error apart from the strange output: "Extra \else" which somehow points to the problem already.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Chapter pages
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize} % - \leftmark
    \fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
}
```

You should close every `\if` statement with a `\fi` command. So, here it should be something like:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Chapter pages
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}\fi           % <--- !
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize} % - \leftmark
    \fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
}
```

The `\fi` could also be placed after `\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}`. It depends on what you want the style to do.